# Getting password and username in spring

Tags: spring-security

Have this as a configuration but it fails to build in netbeans please what am I missing. I using wicket

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd">


<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="select username,password from registration where username=? and Password = ?" />
</authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />


</beans>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it fails to build*?

Comment: @ Aleksandr I have found out why it is not building now how can I getting data from database. That creating the authenticationManager. Link will be appreciated